# Create a task that triggers on a process launch

Tags: task-scheduler, tasks

I'm looking to boost `GTA5.exe`'s priority to "Realtime" whenever it launches
So far, I've tried the following trigger:

```xml
<QueryList>
<Query Id="0" Path="Security">
  <Select Path="Security">
      *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13312 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4688)]] and
      *[EventData[Data[@Name='ProcessName'] and (Data='D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

The code is in
[image: Event Filter]

Comment: Where's your question? What's wrong with the task above?

Comment: The XML doesn't cause the task to trigger when `GTA5.exe`'s process launches

Comment: I know that was not your question... but why not use a 3rd party tool that has this functionality? https://www.raymond.cc/blog/permanently-set-process-priority-in-windows-task-manager-with-prio/

Comment: That could work, but first I'm exploring solutions that don't require installing third-party apps

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [Process Hacker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/processhacker/) gets the job done. It lets me change a process's priority and then save it
Thanks [@Yisroel Tech](https://superuser.com/questions/1780757/create-a-task-that-triggers-on-a-process-launch#comment2780084_1780757)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Why bother using a third-party tool? Just create a batch file that

1. Starts Grand Theft Auto and
2. Then raises its priority, with

   wmic process where name="GTA5.exe" CALL setpriority 128

The priority codes are

```
Realtime       256
High           128
Above Normal 32768
Normal          32
Below Normal 16384
Low             64
```

Avoid Realtime, as it may lock up the OS. See [this Auslogics article](https:////www.auslogics.com/en/articles/change-priority-of-win10-process-with-command-line/) for more information.

Comment: I boost the priority because the game is prone to crashes. When my friend and I are on the same mission, their game is far more likely to crash, even though their CPU and GPU are superior to mine. Boosting the priority to "Realtime" will likely reduce the chance of crashing

Comment: I figured out a way to change the priority via PowerShell, which is my preferred method